# Appended li disappears after submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a todo list using jquery. I have problem when submit the form the appended li appears and disappears immediately. Can anyone help me Please?

Here's my **Jquery** code so far:

```
$(function(){

$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $(this).parent().addClass('completed');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('completed');
    }
});

$('#clearComp').click(function(){
    $('.completed').fadeOut();
});

$('#todo_from').submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});


});
function addTodo(){
    var itemToAdd = $('#txtBox').val();

    if ( itemToAdd ) {
        $('#todoList').append('<li class="todoBlk"><input type="checkbox"         class"checkbox">'+itemToAdd+'</li>');
    }
    $('#txtBox').val('').focus();
}
```

***[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/qegemopapa/1/edit?html,js,output)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because upon pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the form is submitting itself and forcing the page to refresh. So you should use `.preventDefault()` from preventing this from happening:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var itemToAdd = $('#txtBox').val();
    if ( itemToAdd ) {
        $('#todoList').append('<li class="todoBlk"><input type="checkbox" class"checkbox">'+itemToAdd+'</li>');
    }
    $('#txtBox').val('').focus();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This code also allows you to remove the inline JS for the `onsubmit` attribute.

**Update**: I also noticed a problem with your example is that your button fails to clear checked items that are dynamically added. This is because when jQuery is first executed on the page, the `click` listener is only bound to pre-existing elements. Do consider using `.on()` to bind the click event to dynamically added list items. Here's the fixed version: http://jsbin.com/hiyuqikura/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){

  // On submit, prevent default form action and add item if input is not empty
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var itemToAdd = $('#txtBox').val();

    if ( itemToAdd ) {
      $('#todoList').append('<li class="todoBlk"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">'+itemToAdd+'</li>');
    }
    $('#txtBox').val('').focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Listen to click event on dynamically added elements
  $(document).on('click', 'input.checkbox', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
      $(this).parent().addClass('completed');
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('completed');
    }
  });

  $('#clearComp').click(function(){
    $('.completed').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

comment out the $('#todo_from').submit() function and change the form tag to this

```
  <form id="todo_form" onsubmit="addTodo(); return false;">
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got the wrong id here `$('#todo_from').submit`.  Should be `#todo_form`

Comment: why the -1? I changed it in the js bin and it works.